# Boxing and unboxing when using out and ref parameters

Tags: c#, boxing, ref, out, unboxing

Does boxing/unboxing occur when a method accepts an out/ref parameter of a ValueType?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Does using a value type with an `out` parameter cause the variable to be boxed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807086/c-does-using-a-value-type-with-an-out-parameter-cause-the-variable-to-be-box)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does passing a value type in an "out" parameter cause the variable to be boxed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807086/does-passing-a-value-type-in-an-out-parameter-cause-the-variable-to-be-boxed)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For `ref` Keyword Its already mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) that :

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is **no boxing of a value type** when it is passed by reference.

As for `out` keyword:

> The **out** keyword causes arguments to be passed **by reference**. This is **like** the **ref** keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed.