# C# Passing same variable to two "out" parameters

Tags: c#

Is it normal that 'user1' and 'user2' point to the same reference in the example below?

I know that I am passing the same variable 'notUsed' to both parameters, but it's not yet instanced so it does't contain a reference to anything. I was quite shocked to see that user1 and user2 are linked to each other.

```
static void CheckPasswords(out string user1, out string user2)
{
    user1 = "A";
    user2 = "B";

    Console.WriteLine("user1: " + user1);
    Console.WriteLine("user2: " + user2);
}

public static void Main()
{
    string notUsed;
    CheckPasswords(out notUsed, out notUsed);
}
```

Console shows:

```
user1: B
user2: B
```

Comment: What do you mean? How do you know they're linked?

Comment: As you pass the same reference for user1 and user2 into that method, yes it is normal

Comment: @TobiasTheel There are no structs here.

Comment: You're shocked? I fail to see what you would have expected as a result. One variable `notUsed` having two values?

Comment: What are you expecting the output and value of `notUsed` to be and why?

Comment: Your code is : `notUsed = "A"; notused = "B"`, so when you printing you will get same results

Comment: @mason I'm going to assume that both outputs show the same value, though OP failed to include that bit of information.

Comment: Of course it's "not yet instanced" -- it's an `out` variable, those are never instanced before you're calling the method. Nevertheless, it's the same variable referenced twice, *not* two local variables that are "copied out" at the end of the method.

Comment: @itsme86 u are right. had a brain freeze. string is a class ! :D

Comment: You're passing an alias to `notUsed`, so this is the same as if you passed the same reference twice. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807086/does-passing-a-value-type-in-an-out-parameter-cause-the-variable-to-be-boxed

Comment: Consider what you would have expected to happen if you had declared the parameters `ref`. Then consider that `out` is the same case, except you don't initialize the variable first.

Comment: Also, consider that C# is deftly hiding a level of indirection from you -- `user1` and `user2` are *not strings*, they are *references to a string location* (if you must, consider `out string` as if it was a separate type with interesting semantics, same as `ref string`). While `notUsed` holds no reference, `user1` and `user2` *do*. The assignment `user1 = "A"` is really `*user1 = "A"` (if C# used pointers that way, which it does not).

Comment: @Lee I don't care about the value of notUsed, as its name indicates.

Comment: @JeroenMostert When does `notUsed` get its reference?

Comment: @John: at `user1 = "A"`. Since `user1` points to `notUsed`, the reference to `"A"` ends up in `notUsed`. (And then, of course, it is overwritten by the second statement, since `user2` also points to `notUsed`.) The *storage* needed for `notUsed` already exists, even if its *contents* does not at method entry (or more accurately, the contents are indeterminate/inaccessible).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! You can put all of that in an answer if you want and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: " it's not yet instanced so it doesn't contain a reference to anything": An `out` parameter is initially unassigned by definition so it doesn't matter if the variable you pass in is initialized or not, you can't use that value inside the function and, normally, not after the function either. (If an exception occurs inside the function before the variable is assigned, it retains the same value as before the call.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
CheckPasswords(out notUsed, out notUsed);
```

does not pass the *contents* of `notUsed` to the method (as would happen in a method that didn't use `out` parameters), it passes a *reference* to `notUsed` to the method. The same reference twice, in fact. As you say, at this point `notUsed` does not contain a reference itself yet, but that doesn't matter -- we are not doing anything with the contents, in fact, we don't care since we're passing it as `out`. Then this:

```
user1 = "A";
```

does something special because `user1` is not a `string` parameter -- it's an `out string` parameter. Rather than assign a value to some local `user1`, it assigns a value to what `user1` is pointing to -- in this case, `notUsed`. At this point, `notUsed` holds a reference to `"A"`. And then this:

```
user2 = "B";
```

does the same thing, but through the other parameter -- it assigns a reference to `"B"` to `notUsed`. And then these two lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("user1: " + user1);
Console.WriteLine("user2: " + user2);
```

retrieve not the contents of any local variable, but the value in `notUsed`, since both `user1` and `user2` point to it. So, of course, you'll get `"B"` twice.

It is no more shocking than this code:

```
class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

void NotMagic(User user1, User user2) {
    user1.Name = "A";
    user2.Name = "B";

    Console.WriteLine("user1.Name = " + user1.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("user2.Name = " + user2.Name);
}

void Main() {
    User user = new User();
    NotMagic(user, user);
}
```

You probably wouldn't be surprised if this printed `B` twice. That there are two different parameters in `NotMagic` doesn't mean they can't both point to the same thing. Same with `out` and `ref` parameters, except that the syntax will hide the extra indirection for you.

Answer (score 10):

When you use the `out` keyword, you pass by reference. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) Since you are passing by reference, your `user1` and `user2` are both pointing to the same variable. Hence, when you update one, it updates the other.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the variable in by reference. Also, the order of assignments in the method is significant - as written here the variable will contain "B" at the end. If you reverse them, then "A" will be produced.

Compare:

```
user1 = "A"; // notused now contains "A"
user2 = "B"; // notused now contains "B"
// method ends with the variable notused containing "B"
```

Versus:

```
user2 = "B"; // notused now contains "B"
user1 = "A"; // notused now contains "A"
// method ends with the variable notused containing "A"
```